Get failed records from Salesforce write target tool in AWS GLUE job
I am new to this AWS GLUE service, where we are trying to migrate data from S3 to salesforce with Salesforce write target tool(Using Salesforce connection) using Python Script. The actual process has to be, once the process is done, the salesforce provides the jobId/batchId or the failed record data. But here, the glue job is returning null.
def write_to_salesforce(records, entity_name, id_field_names):
    processed_records = []
    failed_records = []

    if records:
        unique_records = list({record['Name']: record for record in records}.values())
        dynamic_frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(spark.createDataFrame(unique_records), glueContext, "dynamic_frame")

        logger.info(f"Transformed {entity_name}_dynamic_frame:")
        dynamic_frame.toDF().show()

        try:
            result = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
                frame=dynamic_frame,
                connection_type="salesforce",
                connection_options={
                    "apiVersion": "v60.0",
                    "connectionName": "Salesforce connection",
                    "entityName": entity_name,
                    "writeOperation": "UPSERT",
                    "idFieldNames": id_field_names
                },
                transformation_ctx="dynamic_frame"
            )
            logger.info(f"result: {result}")
            print(f"res: {result.count()}")
            result.toDF().show()
            processed_records.extend(unique_records)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error occurred: {str(e)}")
            logger.error(f"Error writing to {entity_name}: {e}")
            failed_records.extend(e)
    
    return processed_records, failed_records

We tried different ways to achieve this as shown below, but no luck.

Job Execution with Additional Parameters:
We ran the job with the additional parameter "bulk": true to obtain the batch ID.
Scala Implementation:
We used Scala, along with the Glue library GlueContext, which provides methods like getSink or getSinkWithFormat to write data to Salesforce.
Error Handling with withErrorsAsDynamicFrame():
We tried using the withErrorsAsDynamicFrame() method, which captures error records as a separate dynamic frame. This dynamic frame can then be written to S3 or another location for further analysis.
Unfortunately, this method is not supported by the Salesforce write tool.
Salesforce Debug Logs:
We attempted to track details directly within Salesforce using debug logs. The process uses the composite API, e.g., /services/data/v60.0/composite/sobjects/AddressCatalogRegion__c/ExternalId_t__c
Glue Job Bookmark Feature:
AWS Glue provides a "Job Bookmark" feature to track processed and failed data. However, it does not support Salesforce tools.
Reference: AWS Documentation - Salesforce Connector Limitations
Monitoring and Logging in AWS Glue:
AWS Glue does not automatically monitor or log errors specific to the Salesforce write process. Glue primarily logs and monitors:
Job start and completion status,
Transformation steps,
Errors or exceptions within the Glue job itself (e.g., Spark job failures),
Resource usage (e.g., memory, CPU).
Glue only provides details related to the Glue job ID or the event ID that triggers the Glue job.

Is there a way to get the failed records from the respective job?

You can import additional libraries from https://pypi.org/ that facilitate Salesforce data transfer and communication, and incorporate them into your Glue script as an alternative to using the native Glue methods.

But, if we use libraries or directly connect to salesforce using Bulk APIs in Glue script, we will have to handle the rate limit and stuffs to not cause a timeout issues. Native Glue will handle this by itself right?

You might need to write additional code using this approach, but it will give you greater control and allow for more customization
